# EntityFrameworkCore MySql Contains Not Translated to In

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on a project which uses Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql (1.1.2) for database access.

In my query I am using Contains() in order to check the value of a particular column against a list of possible values. however when I try to execute query shown below,  the library is unable to translate this into a WHERE...IN clause.  This is displayed in the logs as shown.

```
The LINQ expression '{__lookup_0 => Contains((?[x.B].CId?))}' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
The LINQ expression 'Contains((?[x.B].CId?))' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
```

Is this an issue with this particular library or am I missing something?

I have added the code in order to replicate the issue.

```
public class A
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("B")]
    public string BId { get; set; }

    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CId { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }

    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
        loggerFactory.AddProvider(new EFLogProvider());

        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(@"Server=localhost;database=ef;uid=root;pwd=password;");
        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory);
    }
}

public class EFLogger : ILogger
{
    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception,
        Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(formatter(state, exception));
    }
}

public class EFLogProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return new EFLogger();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var a = new A { B = new B { CId = "test" } };

            context.Add(a);

            context.SaveChanges();

            var lookup = new[] {"test", "test2"};

            var res = context.As.Where(x => lookup.Contains(x.B.CId));

            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res));

        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Regards

## Edit

As suggested in the comments this was fixed with version 2.0.0 of EF Core

Comment: The problem seems to be the navigation property, because `Contains(x.BId)` translates correctly. EF Core bug, unrelated to MySQL provider (the same happens with SqlServer).

Comment: Ivan is correct. It was bug in EF Core 1.1.2 `Contains(arg)` can be translated only if arg is member expression. In your case it is null conditional expression. This is supposed to be working in upcoming 2.0.0 release.

Comment: I can confirm this has been fixed with version 2.0.0.  Thank you for your help.